# How to pass a fixed parameter in a click function with knockoutjs?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I want to do that:

```
  <button type="button"  data-bind="click: myFunction(1)" </button>
   <button type="button"  data-bind="click: myFunction(2)" </button>
  <button type="button"  data-bind="click: myFunction(3)" </button>
```

but if I do this every time the page starts, this function is being triggered.I do not want this, I want it to trigger when I click

Comment: "Note 2: Accessing the event object, or passing more parameters" http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html

Comment: @PaulAbbott I made an identical example, but it still runs when loading the page... pls help me

Comment: It's running when you load the page because you're binding to the result of a function rather than to the function itself. You can wrap myFunction inside another anonymous function definition like `click: function(){myFunction(3)}`, which is what @PaulAbbott was referring to

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `myFunction.bind` in `click` binding does the trick. You may try this:

```
<button type="button" data-bind="click: myFunction.bind($data, 1)">one</button>
<button type="button" data-bind="click: myFunction.bind($data, 2)">two</button>
<button type="button" data-bind="click: myFunction.bind($data, 3)">three</button>
```

With `myFunction` defined in View Model like this:

```
self.myFunction = function(n) {
    alert(n);
}
```

alerts only will be fired in response to actual button clicks but not on page loading.

Note that while `self.myFunction` definition has only one parameter `myFunction.bind($data, 1)` should have additional `$data` argument.